# Use javascript to convert special character back to HTML entity code

Tags: javascript, html-entities

In one function of my site, the inner HTML of a div element is changed to include a right arrow. This symbol is included in the innerHTML of "myDiv" as `&#10142;`

In a separate function, I am trying to match the innerHTML of "myDiv" with `&#10142;`

```
function myFunction() {
//Many lines of code then
    var myText = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
    alert(myText);
    if (myText.match(/&#10142;/g)) { //also tried with /&amp;&#35;10142;/g
         alert('Yep');
         myText = myText.replace(/&#10142;/g, " to yield ");
    }
//Many more lines
}
```

When I alert myText as in the function above (before the if statement), the alerted output contains an actual right arrow ➞, not `&#10142;` The problem is that even though `&#10142;` is present in the code to produce the innerHTML of "myDiv" in the first place (in a separate function), in myFunction()
`&#10142;` does not seem to match, since the alert('Yep') is not called.

I looked up and in desperation tried decodeURIComponent() but I was pretty sure this was not going to work and it seemed not to. Can anyone help with this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check it against an actual right arrow, then.

```
function myFunction() {
//Many lines of code then
    var myText = document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML;
    alert(myText);
    if (myText.match(/➞/g)) { //also tried with /&amp;&#35;10142;/g
         alert('Yep');
         myText = myText.replace(/➞/g, " to yield ");
    }
//Many more lines
}
```

Comment: Nice...this worked perfectly. Thank you. So I suppose the lesson here is the innerHTML of any element which includes a non-keyboard character actually contains the non-keyboard character, not the HTML code for that character?

Comment: @TheOneandOnlyChemistryBlob: It’s not a non-keyboard character; it’s any character. But yes, unless it’s necessary for escaping. (You should try to avoid `innerHTML` and work with actual text when you can; it doesn’t have that kind of inconsistency.)

Comment: This solution worked but I just tried matching the different right arrow represented by &rarr; (there are multiple different directional arrows) and this matched too. I guess an arrow is an arrow is an arrow as far as matching innerHTML is concerned :)